# Change printed class name for Quartz Scheduler Job in log files

Tags: tomcat, log4j, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I implemented different Quartz Jobs on a Tomcat application and I would like to change the class display in my log files depending on the output displayed for each Job. For the moment in my log files I have the following:

```
2022-10-20 11:35:49 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2 DEBUG DBA:251 - start getAllA
2022-10-20 11:35:49 DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2 DEBUG DBA:299 - end getAllA
```

Means for each Scheduled Worker the main class is DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-X and I would need to change it.

Here is the declaration of the Quartz Scheduler:

```
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler1 = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    
        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(DB.class)
            .withIdentity("DB", "MyApp")
            .build();

        
        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("DBTrigger", "MyApp")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForever(5))
            .build();

        scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
        scheduler1.startDelayed(120);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("error in scheduler: "+e.toString());
    }
```

I was expecting to get my logs more visible with a TAG Class "DB" but I have "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2", I tried to use the different identities but it does not change the output logs in Log4j.

Any idea how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally answer to my own "a bit stupid" question...
I was using a Pattern for Log4j including %t

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %t %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In my case I do not need this Thread information, so I'm using the following Pattern:

```
[%p] %d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %M - %m%n
```

much more clearer in my logs...but I thought by using withIdentity method I was updating the ThreadName...